# How to let a section flow over the previous section slightly

Tags: html, css

I need help letting the "coiffure" section flow over the "slider" section, as seen on the example page ([example](http://avenue-concept.be/coiffure/)).

NOTE: This is my first question on this platform, so inform me if i'm doing something wrong

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
}

.coiffure {
  background-color: white;
}

.coiffure h1,
h5 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/2.jpg">
  </div>
</section>
<section class="coiffure">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>COIFFURE</h1>
      <h5>VOOR DAMES</h5>

      <p>Laat u vakkundig verwennen door het AVENUE coiffure team. Snit &#45;kleur&#45;lok &#45; en ombre technieken hebben voor ons geen geheimen meer.</p>
      <br>
      <p>Opgeleid en begeleid door het L&#39; oreal Professionelle team staan wij garant voor de laatste nieuwe technieken. Onze hoofdhuid en haarverzorgingsprodukten van Kerastase zorgen mee voor een subliem eindresultaat!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/avenue-concept-coiffure-dames-heist-op-den-berg.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>Bovendien ontwikkelden we voor u het ultieme comfort in een totaal nieuwe setting:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Meer rust, dankzij twee verschillende werkruimtes</li>
        <li>Meer flexibiliteit, dankzij verplaatsbaar meubilair</li>
        <li>Meer rust, dankzij wasunits met zicht op de tuin</li>
      </ul>
      <p>Ontdek en ervaar!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: use position for that.

Answer (score 0):

you have many options to make it but I'll state some options how to make it overlap to the slider

the first one is to add negative margin-top to the **"coiffure section"** to make the section pull back on top just add zindex and position to make on top of the **"slider section"**

the second one is to give the slider a position: absolute and add padding on the body so that it push down